# How to map multiple lists to one dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I used this code:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

in order to map two lists in a dictionary. Where:

```
list1 = ('a','b','c')
list2 = ('1','2','3')
```

The dictionary equals to:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Is there a way to add a third list:

```
list3 = ('4','5','6')
```

so that the dictionary will equal to:

```
{'a': [1,4], 'c': [3,5], 'b': [2,6]}
```

This third list has to be added so that it follows the existing mapping.

The idea is to make this work iteratively in a for loop and several dozens of values to the correctly mapped keyword.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: Note that your inputs are tuples, not lists, but they're effectively the same in this case. Lists use square brackets, tuples use parentheses/round brackets.

Comment: `'c': [3,5], 'b': [2,6]` -- Aren't those numbers in the wrong order? Shouldn't they be `'c': [3, 6], 'b': [2, 5]`? Also FWIW, dicts are unordered, so if it's easier to read, I'm proposing: `{'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
dict((z[0], list(z[1:])) for z in zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

will work. Or, if you prefer the slightly nicer dictionary comprehension syntax:

```
{z[0]: list(z[1:]) for z in zip(list1, list2, list3)}
```

This scales up to to an arbitrary number of lists easily:

```
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, ...]
{z[0]: list(z[1:]) for z in zip(*list_of_lists)}
```

And if you want to convert the type to make sure that the value lists contain all integers:

```
def to_int(iterable):
    return [int(x) for x in iterable]

{z[0]: to_int(z[1:]) for z in zip(*list_of_lists)}
```

Of course, you could do that in one line, but I'd rather not.

Comment: IMO, it's easiest to read with iterable unpacking: `{k: list(t) for k, *t in zip(list1, list2, list3)}`. Then a nested comp isn't so bad: `{k: [int(x) for x in t] for k, *t in zip(*list_of_lists)}`. Or you could use a map: `{k: list(map(int, t)) for k, *t in zip(*list_of_lists)}`

Answer (score 12):

```
In [12]: list1 = ('a','b','c')

In [13]: list2 = ('1','2','3')

In [14]: list3 = ('4','5','6')

In [15]: zip(list2, list3)
Out[15]: [('1', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '6')]

In [16]: dict(zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)))
Out[16]: {'a': ('1', '4'), 'b': ('2', '5'), 'c': ('3', '6')}

In [17]: dict(zip(list1, zip(map(int, list2), map(int, list3))))
Out[17]: {'a': (1, 4), 'b': (2, 5), 'c': (3, 6)}

In [18]: dict(zip(list1, map(list, zip(map(int, list2), map(int, list3)))))
Out[18]: {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

For an arbitrary number of lists, you could do this:

```
dict(zip(list1, zip(*(map(int, lst) for lst in (list2, list3, list4, ...)))))
```

Or, to make the values lists rather than tuples,

```
dict(zip(list1, map(list, zip(*(map(int, lst) for lst in (list2, list3, list4, ...))))))
```

Comment: Would something like this could be modified so it works for n number of lists?

Comment: +1.  I like the `dict(zip(keys,zip(values)))` version.  Especially on python3.x where `zip` is lazy.