# How to zip 3 lists into one dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I have tried adding 2 zipped lists into a dictionary by : dict(zip(list1,list2)) but when I try doing it for 3 lists such that the first list will be the key and the other two would be corresponding values, it gives me an error.

e.g :

```
soc_gp_db=dict(zip(soc_db1,gain_db1,phase_db1))
```

here what I want is that in the dictionary I have something like
soc_db1: gain_db1 , phase_db1

but the error I get is :

> in data_preprocessing
> soc_gp_db = dict(zip(soc_db,gain_db,phase_db))
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Can anybody please help me out here, how can i simply add the lists in the dictionary?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834244/how-to-map-multiple-lists-to-one-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
soc_gp_db = {k: (v1, v2) for k, v1, v2 in zip(soc_db1, gain_db1, phase_db1)}
```

You need some way to express how the values get joined into a 2-tuple, you can't expect `dict` to make an assumption for you.  Hence the explicit `k: (v1, v2)`.